# How often you do this in a cron? - 0 * * * *

Tags: php, cron

```
0 * * * *
```

I use crontab. How often this is done in cron?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It will work once every hour, exactly at x:00.

Keep in mind the format of crontab is:

```
 +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
 |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
 |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
 |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
 |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
 |  |  |  |  |
 *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
```

so 0 in the first position means every minute 0, any hour, and day.

Answer (score 2):

Cron also allows an optional seconds range at the beginning. So 0 * * * * * would mean every second 0 whereas 0 * * * * runs on every minute 0.

Comment: The cron I know doesn't. It would glob the final `*`in some (possibly: home) directory and do weird things there...